# Arc Raster to polygon mesh?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-conversion

I have a landcover raster with 1,364 X 1,303 cells.  I would like to create an output vector mesh depicting every cell outline.  Thus, the vector would contain 1,777,292 polygons.

The raster is a single-band, continuous, signed integer, 32-bit Arc Grid.

The Arc 10.0 Raster to Polygon tool dissolves the output shapefile where adjoining raster cells have the same value.  I don't want the dissolved version - rather I need the outline mesh of every raster cell, regardless of it's value.

Comment: Please focus your question on one GIS product or the other to prevent it being too broad.  You can always research/ask about the other product separately.

Comment: The performance of your 1.8m row table is going to be awful, and it isn't likely to be all that useful. It might be worthwhile to stop and evaluate what you're likely to able to do with this undissolved raster as a vector that you can't do with it as a raster or dissolved vector.

Comment: @PolyGeo are you proposing that I ask the same exact question twice, once for Arc and once for QGIS?

Comment: @Vince you are correct, a polygon layer that large would run pretty slow.  Your comments have forced me to rethink my needs.  Actually, I only need the output mesh for display purposes, not analysis.  So an output polyline mesh might run faster that a polygon mesh.  In any event, I need a mesh that displays every cell outline, even if the resulting output runs slow.

Comment: I'm recommending that you ask it for the GIS software that you are most likely to use. Then, if you do not get an answer that helps, ask it for the other.

Comment: If you choose to work in ArcGIS here are some thoughts:

Comment: 1) Convert the grid cells to points, 2) use the generate near table to get the distance between points but make sure to set a search radius that ensures 4 cell or 8 cell connectivity, 3) use the XY to line tool to create line segments. As suggested by Vince above be cautious with large datasets, and maybe try testing this approach on a subset.

Comment: A polygon vs polyline fishnet wouldn't make a performance difference at 1.8m features, but using some looping to generate 1365x5 line segments at 1/5th the area width by 1304x5 segments 1/5th the area height will give you 13.5k lines that should render efficiently.

Comment: @PolyGeo  Thanks for keeping an eye on this question.  I have developed my own answer to the question, so please take it off hold and I'll then post the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: It's now re-opened.  Can you re-scope its tags to one GIS product at the same time as providing your answer, please?

Comment: To fit the Q&A format would you be able to cut/paste your solution into an answer, please?  It is fine and encouraged to self-answer that way, and we like questions to be just that, rather than a mix of question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

The asker provided the answer below within their question, and so it has been cut/paste to here:

> The Arc Raster to Polygon tool automatically dissolves border lines
>   where adjoining cell values are identical.  There doesn't seem to be
>   any way to force Arc to create a mesh for EVERY raster cell.  So my
>   solution is to create a new raster where every cell has a different
>   value – thus no adjoining cells to dissolve.  I did this by creating a
>   new random raster, based on the raster of interest.
>
> Starting with a 32-bit integer input raster named input123:
>
> 1. Create Random Raster tool:
>
>    - output = output123
>    - output cell size = blank
>    - environment:
>    - output coordinate system = input123
>    - processing extent → extent =  input123
>    - processing extent → snap raster =  input123
>    - raster analysis → cell size =  input123
>    - raster analysis → mask =  input123
>
> The output is a 32-bit floating-point raster with the same number of
>   cells and geometry as the input raster.
>
> 2. Convert the output from above to an integer (an integer raster is requred in the next step).
>
>    - Raster Calculator tool:
>    - Int(“output123” * 1000000)
>
>      - output = output123_int
>
> The output is a 32-bit integer raster
>
> 3. Create the ouput polygon vector mesh.  Alternatively, I could have output as a polyline.
>
>    - Raster to Polygon tool.
>
>      - input = output123_int
>      - field = value
>      - output = mesh123
>      - simplify polygons checked off
>
> Voila!  The output is a vector mesh that contains the outline of the
>   input raster's cells*.
>
> Note that using a random raster carries the risk that the output will
>   potentially have adjoining cells with the same value.  This can be
>   checked by calculating the output vector for polygon size and
>   confirming that all features are the same size.
>
> *Also note that with my data, the vector output contained fewer polygons than the number of input raster cells.  The reason is that
>   the raster had some NoData values along it's edges due to the warping
>   effect of it's projection.  Those NoData cells were not output to the
>   final vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this using [1] 'Create Fishnet'. Set the origin coordinate and resolution to match your raster; set to polygon and check the box to create label points. [2] 'Extract Values to Points' using your raster and the fishnet label points. [3] Join the raster data from your points to the fishnet polygon.